# How can I restore the messages in android?

Tags: android

I am able to getting all messages with its data, type ,address,status etc. but I am not able restore these messages.I tried the following way. It inserts correctly but it shows current date not date of message recieved or send.Please help me how can I restore messages.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "9878782944");
values.put("body", "foo bar");
values.put("date", "1322039220502");
values.put("type", "1");
values.put("status", "-1");
values.put("read", "1");
values.put("protocol", "0");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms"), values);
```

Comment: @SPK did you read a question? way as william is doing is the same as in answer to the question that you post... he is asking why date of message is different, not the one which he insert

Answer (score 0):

Well I am using the code below to restore SMS and in the **"date"** field I am giving Date in **"yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm"** format instead of long in millis, and it is working fine for me.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", numberFile);
values.put("body", bodyFile);
values.put("date", dateFile);
values.put("read", readStatusFile);
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

Also I am telling the insert function about the folder of SMS e.g. inbox. See if this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Date in below given format. Android stores data in Milliseconds. So convert it before passing date to value.

```
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put("address", "8872743939");
  values.put("body", "My Name is Kamal");
  values.put("read", 1);
  java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(Message.getinstance().getDate());
  Long Date = date.getTime();
  values.put("date", Date.toString());
  context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```